# HttpUrlconnection in android working for tablet but not for 2.3.5 device

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am calling webservices from server using "https", I have used simple HttpURLConnection code not HttpsURLConnection, code is working f9 on tablet (OS 4.0.4) but not on my device (2.3.5).

Code is as simple:

```
  URLConnection urlConn = null;
  URL url = new URL("https://myurl");
   urlConn = null;
   urlConn = url.openConnection();


  if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
        try {
            throw new IOException("URL is not an Http URL");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    try {
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
    } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        httpResponsecode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

httpresponsecode is 400, if I call on device, but 200 while calling from tablet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think HttpURLConnection supports following redirects on older os versions. I would recommend using the apache HTTP client instead, it is a lot less buggy.